# Multiple VLANs with Intel I211 and 82576 chips

Tags: windows, vlan, intel

I'm using NICs based on Intel I211 and 82576 chips and I need to create multiple VLANs.
I read online that I can use Intel tools instead of creating virtual switches with HyperV in Windows 10/11, but I can't find these.
Is anyone using the same chips to create multiple VLANs?

Comment: Probably more of a fit for SuperUser, however there is a good writeup here for using the Intel cmdlets for VLAN configuration. https://woshub.com/configure-multiple-vlan-on-windows/